# Making a Delete and Reply button in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

this is my second post on the website. Of all other sites i tried, this one gave the most accurate and useful information!

I'm in a bit of a trouble with buttons, i have a task to make an inbox and to add a "reply" and "delete" button into every instance of the message.

I was indeed wandering if there is a better way to do that than forcing the HTML code into the script, because every message is dynamically generated. Any help and/or suggestions would be very appreciated!(The objects are called from a JSON file).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('public/js/data.json', function(json){
        $.each(json.data, function(i, data){
            var output = '';
         if(data.from.id != '234' && data.from.name != 'Alan Ford'){

            $("#inbox").append(
            output +=
            '<div class="post">'+
            '<div class="h1">'+data.from.name+' - '+data.subject+'</div>'+ //this gives the name of the person who sent the message and the subject
            '<div class="content">'+data.message_formatted+'</div>'+ //The content of the message
                         //buttons should be squeezed left of the date
                           //this gives the date of the message sent
             '<div class="time">'+data.date_sent_formatted.formatted+'</div>'+ 
            '</div>'
    );
         }});
    });

});
var date_sent=convertToDateTime();

function delete_message(id){
    console.log('Delete message with id: '+id);
}

function reply_message(id, sender){
    console.log('Message id: '+id);
    console.log('Reply to: '+sender);
}
```

Comment: jquery html template should do I guess?

Comment: jquery template also http://knockoutjs.com/ might be a good place to start.

Comment: What server technology are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {            //when de html document is loaded
    $(".deleteButton").each(function() {  //for each button with class *deleteButton*
        var button = this;                //we take the html element
        $(button).click(function() {      //and we bind an eventlistener onclick
            alert($(button).attr("id"));  //when the user clicks we tell him the id 
            // code to execute when the user clicks on a delete button
        });
    });

    $(".replyButton").each(function() {
        var button = this;
        $(button).click(function() {
            alert($(button).attr("id"));
            // code to execute when the user clicks on a reply button
        });
    });
});
```

With this you add a class and id to every delete/reply button in the html.
Lets say you have a simple list like this.

```
<div> 
    <button class="deleteButton" id="1">Message 1</div>
    <button class="replyButton" id="1">Message 1</div>

    <button class="deleteButton" id="2">Message 2</div>
    <button class="replyButton"  id="2">Message 2</div>

    <button class="deleteButton" id="3">Message 3</div>
    <button class="replyButton"  id="3">Message 3</div>
</div>
```

Now if you click on one of the buttons, you will get an alert that tells you the id of the button.

Comment: If i didn't get you wrong i don't think that is what i'm looking for.

Let's put it this way. As you can see, by the code, for every generated message that is in the JSON file there should be a "delete" and "reply" button. There is no need to hide them, just display a button for each message. That would delete the given message or give a reply to it.

If i got you wrong i am really sorry, I'm just a bit new with parsing data with DBs and making dynamical inputs.

Comment: Well if you first hide them than the user can not see them. Then when you go through each message you can choose to show them or not. The point is to keep your script free of html. You can insert html dynamically like you do but its alot cleaner if you use the jquery functions to fill, delete, show or hide html elements.

Comment: Apparently we have different thoughts on this that diverge a bit.
If you don't mind, or if it isn't any trouble, can you elaborate a bit?
I know i sound like a bloody fool, but i don't want to implement everything, if it's possible i thrive to understand what i'm doing.
Thank you for all your help!

Comment: No problem :), well let me change the code a little to show you. If i understand correctly you have a list of messages from a db with functions delete and reply.

Comment: Yes, i do :)
I indeed have to say, you guys are really amazing!

Comment: I have to add, my files are separated, as they should be. html/source code, css, JS/jquery(the code posted is in the js tab). Just to add so you don't think i'm forcing everything into HTML.

Comment: Im thinking now, i misinterpreted your question a little as you said. So you got like a mailbox and when you reply some tags says the date,time,name and subject of the message right?

Comment: Ah, that's it! 
Nope, i have made the script for the messages, they appear well and in order. But every message has to have a "delete" and Reply button. 
Imagine your phone and messages on it,  and on the bottom of the every message you have the buttons to delete it or Send it.
I'll put a screenshot and I've added a link to JSFiddle for the full code!

Comment: that should be what you want i think. i edited the answer. each delete button does a getJSON onclick.

Comment: Thanks for the effort anyway... :/

Comment: Sorry dont have alot of time, but basically with this code you can do it. If you have a list, and each list has a button reply and delete and you give all the buttons the same class then when your html document is loaded you can bind the buttons to events. In this case onclick. So what happens is that when you click the event you binded to it will fire and execute the code.